# Concatenate a Collection of Strings (Text) into a comma-delimited string in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow

I'm working with a product called SDocs which generates PDFs (among other things). I need to pass a comma-delimited String of "names" to generate more than one PDF at once.

The names (datatype: text) are already stored in a collection. Assuming I don't know the size of the Collection, is there a way to do this in a Flow without using Apex? I have no problem using Apex, the customer just prefers "No Code".

[image: Flow Pic]

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "The names are already stored in a collection." What **Data Type** is the Collection Variable?

Comment: @Moonpie - As the title says - the Data Type is a "collection of strings (text)". What I'm looking for is to generate a comma-delimited string that is highlighted in yellow in the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am sure that there is more than one way to skin a cat, but here is something quick and dirty I came up with....

---

### Prep

[image]

- **[A]** *DocNamesCollection*: Text Collection Variable
- **[B]** *DocNamesList*: Text Variable that is NOT a Collection
- **[C]** *DocNamesCount*: Number Variable

---

## Flow

[image]

#### Step 1

This is just assigning "DocName01", "DocName02" and "DocName03" to *DocNamesCollection* for me to use in the sample Flow.

#### Step 2

A standard Loop through *DocNamesCollection*

#### Step 3

Add 1 to *DocNamesCount*

#### Step 4

Simple Decision element to check if *DocNamesCount* is greater than 1

First time through it will go straight to **Step 5**; after that, it should go through **Step 6**

#### Step 5

**Add** the current Loop item value to *DocNamesList*:

[image]

#### Step 6

**Add** a comma to *DocNamesList*:

[image]

---

### Results

From the Flow debug:

[image]

---

After you exit the loop, you should be able to replace what you have highlighted in your question with the name of the Text List Variable (*DocNamesList* in the sample).

*As stated earlier, there are multiple ways you could do it. If your original Collection of doc names is a Record Collection, you can grab the count directly. If you "manually" build your Collection of doc names earlier in the Flow, you could instead use the above loop, skip building a Collection, and instead directly add on to a non-Collection variable as shown.*